# Libri per imparare l'italiano

Tags: resources

Sono uno studente di italiano e vorrei alcuni libri per migliorare il mio 
italiano, il mio livello è A1. Grazie!

Comment: Ce ne potrebbero essere a migliaia. Cosa cerchi esattamente? La cosa migliore è cercare tra i libri per bambini di 6-10 anni, ce ne sono di molto validi. C'è la [Feltrinelli](http://www.lafeltrinelli.it/libri-ragazzi-6-10-anni/c-20055/0/) dove ne trovi quanti ne vuoi; a me piacciono molto le Nuove Edizioni Romane, soprattutto la collana [Raccontiamo un classico](http://www.nuoveedizioniromane.it/catalogo/racclass.html). Ce ne sono tante altre.

Comment: @Victor: Cosa cerchi? Metodi di autoapprendimento? Testi de grammatica con esercizi?

Comment: @Charo Libri come fumetti, storie, non difficile di capire.

Comment: [Qui](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3282/488) si trova una domanda simile con alcune risposte interessanti.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ci sono alcune collane di letture graduate per stranieri, libri con esercizi e attività che hanno disponibili anche CD audio per poter ascoltare i testi:

- Collana ***Italiano facile*** di [Alma Edizioni](https://www.almaedizioni.it/it/catalogo/progetti/ADULTI/LET/).
- Collana ***Primiracconti*** di [edizioni Edilingua](http://www.edilingua.it/it-it/Prodotti.aspx?ElementID=ca6410a9-f0dd-4308-90ce-405b9560565a&Action=First).
- Collana ***Imparare leggendo*** di [Cideb Editrice](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/6-italian-catalogue).

Se preferisci leggere le storie a fumetti, ci sono anche queste collane:

- Collana ***L’italiano con i fumetti*** di [Alma Edizioni](https://www.almaedizioni.it/it/catalogo/progetti/ADULTI/FUM/).
- Collana ***Imparare l'italiano con i fumetti*** di [edizioni Edilingua](http://www.edilingua.it/it-it/Prodotti.aspx?ElementID=e93596e6-e34a-4958-a88c-e2d8190b2a89&Action=First) (di livello un po' più alto, però).

Comment: Molte grazie per la tua risposta!