# Suggerimenti di libri per un novellino

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, resources

Sto imparando l'italiano da alcuni anni ormai, ma recentemente ho iniziato a prestare maggiore attenzione. In questo momento, **mi considero uno studente di livello A2 o B1**. Quando ho imparato l'inglese molti anni fa, ho letto libri di inglese di base e questo mi ha aiutato molto.

Siccome voglio migliorare il mio italiano, **vorrei chiedere alcuni suggerimenti di libri che possa leggere**. Possono essere di qualsiasi genere. Voglio solo un libro che possa aiutare la mia grammatica e il mio vocabolario. Potrebbe essere un romanzo o un libro di fiabe.

Comment: Davvero non capisco perché questo post ottenga un voto negativo. C'era una domanda simile nello Stack **per il livello A1**, che ha ottenuto voti positivi (https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2381/libri-per-imparare-litaliano?rq=1= È così arbitrario. Posso solo chiedere informazioni sulla grammatica o sul vocabolario qui? Perché non posso chiedere informazioni sulle risorse che potrebbero aiutarmi?

Comment: Ti suggerisco di postare questa domanda su https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tamuno: Come non italiana che ha anche avuto un livello B1, direi che sei in grado di leggere praticamente qualsiasi libro. Forse è per questo che la domanda ha avuto un voto negativo: le possibili raccomandazioni sono tantissime che la domanda diventa "opinion-based" ("this question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations"). Tieni anche conto del fatto che una domanda che è considerata come "opinion-based" può finire chiusa.

Comment: Se quello che stai cercando sono "graded readers", ne puoi trovare  [qui](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3282/) (a me però i cosiddetti "graded readers" mi annoiano tremendamente e ho sempre preferito leggere veri romanzi).

Comment: Hai ragione, @tamuno, anche quella domanda sull'A1 era “opinion-based” e, presumibilmente, inadatta al formato di questo sito. Grazie per la segnalazione.

Comment: Non mi pare che si possa parlare di “opinion based”. In altri siti su SE si trovano domande su “liste di risorse utili” per un certo argomento.

Comment: Non so, @egreg. Il problema che vedo io è: possiamo fare una lista con tutti i possibili libri in italiano che potrebbe leggere uno studente di livello B1? Forse "opinion-based" non è il modo migliore di descrivere questo tipo di domande, ma sarebbe qualcosa come "list questions, where every answer is equally valid". Da [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "avoid asking subjective questions where …  every answer is equally valid ...".  Secondo me, il fatto che un libro sia adatto a un livello B1 è qualcosa di piuttosto soggettivo.

Comment: @egreg: Poi, parecchi anni fa c'è stata questa [domanda sul sito Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1249/), ma tanto la domanda come le risposte hanno ricevuto pochi voti, quindi non credo si possa dire che come comunità si sia arrivato a un consenso. Come quattro anni e mezzo fa, continuo a pensare che la informazione che si dà sull'argomento come comunità sia piuttosto confusa e contraddittoria.

Comment: @egreg: “please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site. "How to improve my Italian?" or "What's a good tool for...?" [...] Requests for resources” (https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Direi proprio che “alcuni suggerimenti di libri che possa leggere. [...] Voglio solo un libro che possa aiutare la mia grammatica e il mio vocabolario” rientri esattamente in “how to improve my Italian” e nella richiesta di risorse.

Comment: Prima di tutto, mi dispiace davvero se la mia domanda abbia causato qualche disturbo nello "stack".  Pensavo davvero che la mia domanda non fosse così soggettiva. Perché mentre stavo ancora imparando l'inglese, c'erano alcune parole specifiche e alcuni "tempi" associati ai livelli A1, A2, B1 ecc. Ad esempio, se conosci le prime 100 parole di base (frutta, parti della casa, animali ecc.) e il tempo presente, verrai considerato uno studente di livello A1. (https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/vocabulary/beginner-to-pre-intermediate). Ecco perché ho posto la mia domanda.

Comment: Mi chiedevo solo se esiste un "libro di riferimento" per gli studenti di A2-B1 che copriva queste parole e forse i tempi verbali. (che è noto agli insegnanti, ecc.) Prima di porre la domanda, ho fatto alcune ricerche sul web e uno dei suggerimenti era "I sentiero dei nidi di ragno". So che ci sono alcuni libri di "graded reader" in italiano per il livello A2-B1, ma volevo leggere "libri reali" scritti da scrittori famosi come Italo Calvino (se posso). Comunque, proverò a porre domande più oggettive in futuro.

Comment: Non hai causato nessun disturbo, @tamuno. E sono completamente d'accordo con te che è preferibile leggere "libri veri". Puoi dare un'occhiata a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10335/) e a [quest'altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5634/) (che credo abbiano lo stesso "problema" di questa).

Comment: @tamuno: Come in una di quelle domande, ho cercato sul sito web della Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona se c'è un elenco di libri raccomandati per gli studenti che hanno il livello A2 e stanno studiando per acquisire il livello B1, ma, purtroppo, questo tipo di liste non si trovano più (perlomeno sul sito della Scuola di Barcellona).

Comment: @tamuno: Confermo che non hai certo creato nessun disturbo, e capisco bene il senso della tua domanda (cose simili mi interessano per un'altra lingua che sto studiando). Ma un conto è chiedere quali siano i programmi, il lessico, la grammatica etc. corrispondenti ad A1, A2, B1 e così via: questa sarebbe una domanda ben precisa. Un conto è, fra tutti i libri del mondo, chiedere consigli su quali siano adatti a un certo livello. Forse certi [subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/italianlearning/) o altri siti simili sono più adatti a domande “aperte” di questo tipo.

Comment: @DaG and others: I've tried to reopen [this discussion on Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1249/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ecco un elenco di libri che erano raccomandati dalla Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona agli studenti che hanno il livello A2 e stanno studiando per acquisire il livello B1:

- Antonio Tabucchi: *Sostiene Pereira*.
- Luigi Garlando: *Per questo mi chiamo Giovanni*.
- Niccolò Ammaniti: *Io non ho paura*.
- Valerio Massimo Manfredi: *Chimaira*.
- Stefania Bertola: *Biscotti e sospetti*.
- Daria Bignardi: *Non vi lascerò orfani*.
- Italo Calvino: *Gli amori difficili*.
- Marco Videtta e Massimo Carlotto: *Nordest*.
- Gianrico Carofiglio: *Il passato è una terra straniera*.
- Elsa Morante: *L’isola di Arturo*.
- Margherita Oggero: *La collega tatuata*.
- Gabriele Romagnoli: *Navi in bottiglia*.
- Michele Serra: *Gli sdraiati*.
- Domenico Seminerio: *Il manoscritto di Shakespeare*.
- Fabio Volo: *Un posto nel mondo*.
- Andrea De Carlo: *Di noi tre*.
- Simonetta Agnello Hornby: *La Mennulara*.
- Giorgio Bassani: *Il giardino dei Finzi-Contini*.

Comment: Non sono per niente sicura di far bene scrivendo questa risposta poiché io stessa ho espresso il dubbio che questa domanda fosse adatta al formato di questo sito. Non è coerente da parte mia e capisco perfettamente che questa è la ragione del downvote. Tuttavia, forse sarebbe buono riaprire [questo tipo di dibattito](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/should-we-define-which-questions-asking-for-resources-are-on-topic) perché la mia impressione è che, come comunità, non mostriamo di avere le idee molto chiare su quali domande che chiedono risorse vi sembrano adatte al sito.

Comment: Sono riuscita a trovare questo elenco: l'avevo scaricato anni fa quando mi scrissi al corso del livello C1.

Comment: Grazie mille. Questi sono fantastici! Anche se potrebbe essere "opinion-based", mi sento ancora nella giusta direzione. Apprezzo molto il numero di libri diversi, dal momento che i libri scritti in italiano a volte sono molto difficili da trovare in paesi stranieri (o almeno dove attualmente vivo). Inoltre, sono ancora molto nuovo su Stackexhange. Non sapevo nemmeno del "meta.stackexchange" fino a due giorni fa. Dopo aver letto ciò che è scritto su https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask, ora vedo come la mia domanda può essere soggettiva.

Comment: Tuttavia, vorrei sottolineare che a volte ci sono risposte "opinion-based" che sono accettate dalla maggior parte delle persone. Ad esempio, nel mio paese natale, il ministero dell'educazione (un consiglio di insegnanti all'interno del ministero) ha pubblicato elenchi di "100 opere di base da leggere" per i bambini delle scuole medie, superiori, ecc., Più di 30 anni fa. Ancora oggi la maggior parte di questi libri sono ancora considerati "go-to-books" e sono molto apprezzati dalla maggior parte delle persone.

Comment: @tamuno: Le opinioni sono (entro certi limiti) cose ottime e utilissime, e così i consigli sui libri da leggere e così via. Fa bene il tuo ministero a offrirne, e te ne posso offrire (o chiedere a te per la tua lingua) in un'altra sede. È solo che il formato dei siti StackExchange è pensato più per domande che hanno risposte specifiche, documentate, che non per consigli di lettura e simili.

Comment: @DaG e altri: Vorrei aggiungere che la mia impressione è che, fino al momento presente, la comunità abbia deciso di lasciare aperte questo tipo di domande. C'era [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1250/) una proposta di fare altrimenti, ma, in quattro anni e mezzo non si è fatto nulla di tutto questo, immagino che per il fatto che la proposta aveva soltanto tre voti fino a due giorni fa. Secondo me, una domanda o si chiude o si cerca di rispondere: quello che non ha senso è lasciare una domanda aperta e cercare di non dare nessuna risposta.

Comment: Adesso c'è l'opportunità di cambiare questo se lo crediamo necessario o perlomeno di discuterlo con l'obiettivo di dare un'immagine più coerente al riguardo.